# How do I have a login form with multiple post and get requests in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, flask

How do I have a login form with multiple post and get requests in flask. Basically, I have a login page, first I would like to check whether the username is taken yet, then post the password part of the form. This all should happen in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two ajax request, one for the username check another one for login. Or one ajax and one form post.

```
<!-- login.html -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
    <p id="username-text"></p>
    <label for="username">Password</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $('#username').keyup(function() {
        console.log(";ok")
        data = {'username': $('#username').val()}
        $.post("{{ url_for('check_username') }}", data, function(data, status){
            $('#username-text').text(data['msg']);
          });
    })
</script>
```

If you want to redirect your page after login, then just post the data as it is. If you don't want to redirect, write one more ajax for authentication.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # validate you creds ....
        authenticate(request.POST)
        # redirect() if needed
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/check_username', methods=["POST"])
def check_username():
    username = request.form['username']
    # write the query for username check
    found = ''
    if found:
        return {'msg': 'Username taken'}
    else:
        return {'msg': 'Username is available'}
```